# Load from cloud in Android Studio

Tags: android, arraylist, dropbox

I've got an ArrayList. I saved it locally using SharedPreferences but I want to save and reload it from a cloud (Dropbox or Google Drive). 
Is there a way to do that in Android Studio? 
Thanks for your help. 

*(My Class is comparable and parcelable, I don't know if that's helpful)*

Comment: you could use a network call to fetch your project required data on apps start, why trouble android studio? any specific reason?

Comment: Can you give an example of a network call? It should be android studio because I want to do it in an app.

Comment: o_o yes i mean in your app through java code, your IDE is android studio.
and lemme see if i ould dig up some code. but seriously api consumption is a framework ..realized using any number of ways, for your scenario it would depend on how you want to rrealize it. Maybe a backend server or text file in a filesever location like dropbox etc which you just have fetch using a  GET http requests.
ill see if i can dig up a few links for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've worked with jsoup in another project. Maybe that's a way to do it.